# android manifest being choosey

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, manifest

Ok, so I've got my Android application and it wont boot with a "unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{}" error, basically theres something wrong in my manifest file that won't let the application launch the first activity. I made a new but essentially duplicated project (manually copying across the Java+XML code for Main, second + third 'tester' activities, and of course Strings). I left the manifest of the new project as it is but added the activity lines for the tester. I wanted everything as stock basically so nothing could go wrong, and nothing did, the application loaded on emulator and my phone alright.

So I copy the new manifest to my old project in an effort to 'default' it, and I copy and pasted the tester activity code that was already there and worked, for the other 3 activity's. Suddenly it doesn't want to work. Everything is there, but what's the problem? (note the icon drawable is changed but that's nothing to do with it). All the activity names match up to package names and whatnot. Could this be a bug? I honestly cannot find anything wrong.

Duplicate (+ working) code

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo3"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Cal"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cal" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Breads"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_breads" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Old (+ not working) code

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Cal"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cal" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Breads"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_breads" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Gal"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_gal" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Tut"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tut" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Rec"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rec" >
    </activity>
 </application>
```

EDIT: I just copied and pasted the codes into the search bar on Chrome (changing the droid:icon and droid:label to fit) and they are exactly the same!! What?! Am I not allowed to have 6 activities or something?

Errors:

```
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ollygrov.bakerspride/com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1825)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Main.<init>(Main.java:19)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  ... 11 more
09-04 11:34:58.665: E/Trace(765): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-04 11:34:59.095: D/AndroidRuntime(765): Shutting down VM
09-04 11:34:59.095: W/dalvikvm(765): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ollygrov.bakerspride/com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1825)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Main.<init>(Main.java:19)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
09-04 11:34:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
```

Comment: Could you please post your stacktrace/errors

Comment: There is a NPE happening at Main.java (line 19). What's there?

Comment: Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.r); :S

Comment: Are you sure that a View w/ that id exists in your main layout? Because the error says that it doesn't exist.

Comment: It exists, I realised I typed that and 3 others at the beginning but decided to use XML OnClick method + a switch statement instead, deleted them all and it works, thanks for your help! Next time I'll look more closely at the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `Main` Constructor:

```
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1825)
09-04 11:33:04.895: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at com.ollygrov.bakerspride.Main.<init>(Main.java:19)
```

In line 19 of `Main.java` you are trying to call `findViewById()` which will obviously not work. It is way to early to call such code in the constructor.
My best guess is, that you need to move EVERYTHING from the cronstructor to `onCreate()` of the Activity.

Normally you don't need a custom constructor in Activities or Fragments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually have another incident now but from the same problem. I swear I've always declared constructers in the main body. I moved them all to below the onCreate method and still it logs an error at the first constructer line. Can you tell me the appropriate location to have the constructers? Would it be better to move them all to a method and then call the method in onCreate?

Comment: With Android Activities and Fragments: NEVER have constructors. period.

Comment: BTW: if the answer is correct, you should be so nice and accept it.

Comment: Can you explain to me why? How else would I be able to assign integers to id's? I use Java with XML

Comment: Just do it in onCreate() as i told you before. AFTER you inflated the layout. Please read some basic android tutorials or check out exampled from http://d.android.com